# Using jQuery ui slider and radio buttons to perform a calculation

Tags: radio-button, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to replicate the calculator on http://www.andyloos.co.uk/calculator/. Is it possible to see how exactly they do their calculation? To see their Java-Script?

I have got as far as http://jsfiddle.net/jstyl_es/Sqsuu/ but I don't really know Java-Script well enough to take it forward. Can anyone help?

```
<div id="slider1"></div>

<div id="slider2"></div>

<div id="option">
  <input type="radio"  name="timeselect" value="optionA" />
  Less than 6 hours
  <input type="radio"  name="timeselect" value="optionB" />
  More than 6 hours
</div>

<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Estimate">        

</div>



`$(function() {
  $( "#slider1" ).slider({
    value:0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100000,
    step: 50,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount1" ).val( ui.value );
    }
  });
  $( "#amount1" ).val($( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ) );
});

$(function() {
  $( "#slider2" ).slider({
    value:0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100000,
    step: 50,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.value );
    }
  });
  $( "#amount2" ).val($( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Comment: The link given is broken. So, it's impossible to understand your requirements.